# Get a request from api every 10 seconds

Tags: php, json, request, limit

I keep hitting the max request limit on an api. I have my page refresh itself every 10 seconds with `meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"`. But I know this is not the correct way to update this data. How would I limit this request to every 10 seconds from the source (below)

```
$url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/ETHusd";    
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);    
$eth = $json["last_price"];
```

Comment: If you keep hitting the max request limit on the API, how is moving the problem of polling to the server going to solve that?

Comment: The meta refresh is a perfectly valid way to update. The only issue might be if the results get cached. As for refreshing every 10 seconds in PHP, you could ``sleep(10)`` but that's probably not what you want, either.

Comment: @kmoser `sleep(10)` just causes PHP to pause execution for 10 seconds. It has nothing to do with polling.

Comment: @BenM, If the OP's code is put in a loop which calls ``sleep(10)`` before repeating, it will cause the script to poll every 10 seconds.

Comment: That'd be an infinite loop, then? ;)

Comment: It does update infinity. I just need it to update less than 60 times a minute. I think kmoser has it. But I don't know how I would add a sleep to this?

Comment: It's only an infinite loop if it loops infinitely :). If it loops, say, 100 times, then it's not infinite.

Comment: I loaded the data from your api url. It returns the unix timestamp of your request as one of the parameters. Just use that as a conditional for polling again?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained or shown what your script is doing with `$eth` but this should work:

```
$url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/ETHusd";    
while(TRUE) {
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $eth = $json["last_price"];
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: I'm just shortening it so when I call it back later in a chart it's less cluttered. Also, I get "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" from that code. I changed the max time to 160 in php.ini but it reached that limit too.

Comment: You can change the max execution time to 0, which will make it unlimited.